# optimizing a SPARQL query when using a custom function in Jena

Tags: java, sparql, jena, geosparql

I have the following SPARQL query on a Owl Ontology, using Jena:

```
SELECT ?label ?distance
WHERE {
  ?wpt rdf:type inav:Waypoint .
  ?wpt inav:Label ?label .
  ?ac  rdf:type inav:Aircraft .
  ?ac  inav:Label "myAircraft" .
  ?wpt inav:hasExactGeometry ?geom .
  ?geom inav:asWKT ?wkt .
  ?ac inav:hasExactGeometry ?geom2 .
  ?geom2 inav:asWKT ?wkt2 .
  BIND (geof:distance(?wkt, ?wkt2, <http://www.opengis.net/def/uom/OGC/1.0/nauticalMile>) as ?distance)
}
ORDER BY ASC(?distance )
LIMIT 1
```

The idea is that:

- I have an `Aircraft` called "myAircraft"
- I have several Waypoints
- I search for the closest `Waypoint` using GeoSPARQL
- I want to return the label of the closest `Waypoint`, and it's distance to the "myAircraft" `Aircraft`

This query works without any problem.

Now I am adding a custom vocabulary using Jena `FunctionFactory`. In my case I want to retrieve in real time the visibility of the meteo in meters at the position of the waypoint  (to take an example). In order to do that, I created a custom vocabulary with one `visibility` word. It has only one argument which is the `Label` of the `Waypoint` in my case.

I then changed my query as following:

```
SELECT ?label ?distance ?visibility
WHERE {
  ?wpt rdf:type inav:Waypoint .
  ?wpt inav:Label ?label .
  ?ac  rdf:type inav:Aircraft .
  ?ac  inav:Label "myAircraft" .
  ?wpt inav:hasExactGeometry ?geom .
  ?geom inav:asWKT ?wkt .
  ?ac inav:hasExactGeometry ?geom2 .
  ?geom2 inav:asWKT ?wkt2 .
  BIND (geof:distance(?wkt, ?wkt2, <http://www.opengis.net/def/uom/OGC/1.0/nauticalMile>) as ?distance)
  BIND (my:visibility(?wpt) as ?visibility)
}
ORDER BY ASC(?distance )
LIMIT 1
```

It also works without any problem, but I remarked in my Debugger that the Java `visibility` function is called for every `Waypoint` in the Ontology, not only the closest one. If I have a lot of waypoints, I will have to call my Java function for `Waypoint`, when ideally I would like to do that for only one of them, the closest one.

Is there a way to do that to speed-up this query? (the idea is that in real-life I would call a meteo service for my Waypoint, but I do not want to do that for every `Waypoint`, but only the one I found in my query).

Comment: order by forces to compute all solutions first, then just take the first according to the ĹIMIT 1´ - you have to put your initial query into a subquery, and in the outer query you can apply your custom function. Or you just use your function in the projection part

Comment: `SELECT ?label ?distance (my:visibility(?wpt) AS ?visibility)
WHERE {
  ?wpt rdf:type inav:Waypoint .
  ?wpt inav:Label ?label .
  ?ac  rdf:type inav:Aircraft .
  ?ac  inav:Label "myAircraft" .
  ?wpt inav:hasExactGeometry ?geom .
  ?geom inav:asWKT ?wkt .
  ?ac inav:hasExactGeometry ?geom2 .
  ?geom2 inav:asWKT ?wkt2 .
  BIND (geof:distance(?wkt, ?wkt2, <http://www.opengis.net/def/uom/OGC/1.0/nauticalMile>) as ?distance)
}
ORDER BY ASC(?distance )
LIMIT 1`

Comment: `SELECT ?label ?distance ?visibility 
{{SELECT ?label ?distance 
WHERE {
  ?wpt rdf:type inav:Waypoint .
  ?wpt inav:Label ?label .
  ?ac  rdf:type inav:Aircraft .
  ?ac  inav:Label "myAircraft" .
  ?wpt inav:hasExactGeometry ?geom .
  ?geom inav:asWKT ?wkt .
  ?ac inav:hasExactGeometry ?geom2 .
  ?geom2 inav:asWKT ?wkt2 .
  BIND (geof:distance(?wkt, ?wkt2, <http://www.opengis.net/def/uom/OGC/1.0/nauticalMile>) as ?distance)

}
ORDER BY ASC(?distance )
LIMIT 1}   BIND (my:visibility(?wpt) as ?visibility)}`

Comment: by the way, is there any reason for not using the common property `rdfs:label` What is the point of defining your own label property when it is part of the standard RDF vocabulary?

Comment: and what you added is not a custom vocabulary but a custom "function"

Comment: Yes sorry I changed the title for accuracy

Comment: For the Label, there are no good reason for that, I reused an old Ontology where this Label was there, but it was not there for a good reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the very informative answer of UninformedUser:

```
SELECT ?label ?distance ?visibility  
{
   {SELECT ?label ?distance  
    WHERE {   
      ?wpt rdf:type inav:Waypoint .   
      ?wpt inav:Label ?label .  
      ?ac  rdf:type inav:Aircraft . 
      ?ac  inav:Label "myAircraft" . 
      ?wpt inav:hasExactGeometry ?geom .   
      ?geom inav:asWKT ?wkt .   
      ?ac inav:hasExactGeometry ?geom2 .   
      ?geom2 inav:asWKT ?wkt2 .   
      BIND (geof:distance(?wkt, ?wkt2, <http://www.opengis.net/def/uom/OGC/1.0/nauticalMile>) as ?distance)  
   } ORDER BY ASC(?distance ) LIMIT 1
}  BIND (my:visibility(?wpt) as ?visibility)
}
```